# Using GWT Cell Browser to create a product Taxonomy

Tags: gwt, user-interface, data-structures, treeview

I am in a very big issue. I need to be able to create a product taxonomy view together with ADD,DELETE,MODIFY functionality. On the first level the products will be general and as we go deep, it will become more specific.

for e.g. on the first level,

```
 ->Computer
     -->Keyboard
        -->Qwerty Keyboard
        -->... Keyboard
     -->Mouse
        -->Wireless Mouse
           -->2 Key Mouse
           -->3 Key Mouse
        -->MagicMouse
 ->Other
     ....
 ->Furniture
```

Can someone give me an idea about this??

Comment: Have you tried SmartGWT already? Their demo application in showcase http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/ is quite similar to your need.

Comment: In fact, I need to use the normal gwt because of the restriction of the university project.

Comment: There are examples with source code for each of the Cell Widgets on the GWT showcase: http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have been able to do it, the main idea is the listdataprovider